# Users cannot change their password when connecting to OS X Server Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-server, afp, network-user

I set up a bunch of users on my OS X Server 3 (Mavericks) requesting they reset the temporary password I gave them.
However, no one is able to do that: when connecting via AFP for the first time, they enter their temporary password and are asked to change it, but the form does not accept any value. I don't know if it doesn't accept the current password or the new passwords but I suspect the first: any subsequent login doesn't accept the old password and refuses to even show the change password form.

GV jan 13th: We are having the same issue; Our admins do not seem to have this problem, the weird thing is only the other users have this issue.

Comment: Any console logs on the server?

Comment: Please also check or show your settings under Users in Server.app and/or Server Admin/Workgroup Manager (I forgot which).

Comment: How exactly is a user going about the password change. Operation. From a web browser on anger computer? From a Mac hat somehow is set up to authenticate to the server? From a PC? Also the edit by @gvtw isn't clear to me what an admin has to do with users self administering their passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mavericks server with this issue, I have found that if a client is using Mountain Lion or earlier, it resets fine. But Mavericks or El Capitan... no dice. So bizarrely, it may in part be a client issue. Hope that helps you get to the bottom of it.